# Using while in list comprehension or generator expressions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, recipe, generator-expression

I can use `if` and `for` in list comprehensions/generator expressions as

```
list(i for i in range(100) if i*i < 30)
```

I know this is not the most efficient but bear with me as the condition could be much more complicated and this is just an example. However, this still goes through hundred iterations and only yields a value in the first 6. Is there a way to tell the generator expression where to stop with something like this:

```
list(i for i in range(100) while i*i < 30)
```

However, `while` is not understood in generator expressions. So, my question is, how do I write a generator expression with a stopping condition so it does not continue computation, even if it doesn't yield new values.

Comment: Just a note: you can generate a list directly by using `[i for i in range(100)]`

Comment: Curiously, there was [PEP3142](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3142/) open at the time this question was asked. The use case given is almost exactly this one. Guido nuked it in May, 2013

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The various functions in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) (`takewhile()` comes to mind) can help.

Answer (score 27):

Because the syntax of `takewhile()` and `dropwhile()` is not the *clearest*, here are the actual examples of your question:

```
>>> [i for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x*x<30, range(10))]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [i for i in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x*x<30, range(10))]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Know that the author of itertools [has questioned](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/753516-fate-itertools-dropwhile-itertools-takewhile) whether to deprecate these functions.

Comment: What would be the recipe in case these functions are deprecated?

Comment: Just look at the Python docs for [itertools.takewhile](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [itertools.dropwhile](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile). Each has the straight Python equivalent.

Comment: isn't just `list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x*x<30, range(10)))` easier than a comprehension here

Comment: @wim I pointed the link at the same message, different host. Thanks