# Using 'while' loops in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Say I have a function:

```
x=[]
i=5
while i<=20:
     x.append(i)
     i=i+10
return x
```

Is there a way to convert it to a list comprehension like this?

```
newList = [i=05 while i<=20 i=i+10]
```

I get a syntax error.

Comment: `i` isn't changing in your *while* loop, so it'll simpy *whirl* forever.

Comment: `i` is never modified, so `i <= 5` is always true, and the `while` loop will never exit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using while in list comprehension or generator expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505891/using-while-in-list-comprehension-or-generator-expressions)

Comment: I fixed it, in the real code it's incremented, just forgot to add it here. It still does not work

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that initializing an integer and manually incrementing it within a `while` loop is the wrong way to iterate over a sequence of numbers in Python. Your first code block would more appropriately be `x = []; for i in range(5, 21, 10): x.append(i)`, which has a much clearer path for conversion into a comprehension.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need a list comprehension for that. `range` will just do:

```
list(range(5, 21, 10)) # [5, 15]
```

A `while` loop is not possible inside of a list comprehension. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
def your_while_generator():
    i = 5
    while i <= 20:
        yield i
        i += 10

[i for i in your_while_generator()]
```

Answer (score 19):

**No, you cannot use `while` in a list comprehension.**

From the [grammar specification of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), only the following atomic expressions are allowed:

```
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |    '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |    '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |    NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
```

The expression corresponding to a list comprehension - `testlist_comp` looks like the following in Python 3:

```
testlist_comp: (test|star_expr) ( comp_for | (',' (test|star_expr))* [','] )
```

Here, the only statements allowed are

```
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
star_expr: '*' expr
comp_for: [ASYNC] 'for' exprlist 'in' or_test [comp_iter]
```

where

```
comp_if: 'if' test_nocond [comp_iter]
comp_iter: comp_for | comp_if
```

There is not a single `while` statement allowed anywhere. The only keywords you are allowed to use is a `for`, for a *for* loop.

## Solution

Use a `for` loop, or take advantage of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any syntax for this, but you can use itertools. For example:

```
In [11]: from itertools import accumulate, repeat, takewhile

In [12]: list(takewhile(lambda x: x <= 20, accumulate(repeat(1), lambda x, _: x + 10)))
Out[12]: [1, 11]
```

*(That's not Pythonic though. The generator solution or explicit solution should be preferred.)*