# Create a list of random numbers and filter the list to only have numbers larger than 50

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am using list comprehension to create a list of random numbers with numpy. Is there a way to check if random number generated is larger than 50 and only then append it to the list.

I know I can simply use:

```
numbers = [np.random.randint(50,100) for x in range(100)]
```

and that would solve the issue, but I just want to know if its possible to somehow check if np.random.randint(1,100) generated number greater than 50

Something like

```
numbers = [np.random.randint(1,100) for x in range(100) if {statement}]
```

Because comparing np.random.randit generates another number which is not the same as the first one.

I just want to know if there is a possibility to filter generated numbers before adding them to a list.

Comment: There is... but you'd have to do it in a nested loop which would be ugly, use a for loop. fyi its `[x for x in [randint().. for _ in range(100)] if x > 50]`

Comment: Thank you, yea, it is kind of ugly, but does the job. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: let me know of my answer helps

Comment: Doesn't  randint(50, 100) generates numbers above 50?

Comment: Hi @makis, your solution does not work because it compares x to 50 which basically just adds 50 random numbers or whatever you compare x to.

Comment: Hi, @DanielMesejo, yes, I know how I can solve it using randint(50,100), I wanted to know if I can filter randint(1,100) before adding it to the list.

Comment: See my answer below: `numbers = [x for x in (np.random.randint(1,100) for iter in range(100)) if x > 50]`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @makis, that is a sneaky one-liner1! Could you elaborate how does iter work here? Does each time randint generates a number it is held by iter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: See [Can a lambda function call itself recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python) and use a recursive lambda to set the list item. Then you can call it a singular list comprehension-

Comment: @JonasPalačionis I am going to explain everything in my answer

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Do you want to control over the number of values you get in `numbers`? `[np.random.randint(50,100) for x in range(100)]` and `np.random.randint(50, 100, 100)` are NOT equivalent to `filter`-based solutions like `filter(lambda x: x > 50, np.random.randint(1, 100, 100))` or `[x for x in np.random.randint(1, 100, 100) if x > 50]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use numpy, so we can leverage indexing method.

```py
my_array = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=100)
mask = my_array > 50
print(my_array[mask]) # Contain only value greater than 50
```

But of course, the best way to do what you want is that.

```py
results = np.random.randint(51,100, size=100)
# If you really need a list
results_list = results.tolist()
```

Please, don't loop over a numpy array in general.

Edit : replace my_list by my_array based on @norok2 comment.

Edit2 : Speed considerations

### Numpy

#### With mask

```py
%%timeit
my_array = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=100)
mask = my_array > 50
my_array[mask]
```

> 5.31 µs ± 127 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

10,000,000 elements:

> 1 loop, best of 3: 198 ms per loop

#### With numpy where (@Severin Pappadeux anwser)

```py
%%timeit
q = np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000)
m = np.where(q > 50)
q[m]
```

> 20.9 µs ± 663 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

10,000,000 elements:

> 1 loop, best of 3: 196 ms per loop

### Pure python

### Part of @Alexander Cécile answer

```py
%%timeit
rand_nums = (random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(10))
arr = [val for val in rand_nums if val > 50]
```

> 19.4 µs ± 1.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

10,000,000 elements:

> 1 loop, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop

### Mix numpy and list

#### @DrBwts answer

```py
%%timeit
number = [x for x in np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=100) if x > 50]
```

> 28.9 µs ± 1.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

10,000,000 elements:

> 1 loop, best of 3: 2.76 s per loop

#### @makis answer

```py
%%timeit 
numbers = [x for x in (np.random.randint(1,100) for iter in range(100)) if x > 50]
```

> 164 µs ± 19.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

10,000,000 elements:

> 1 loop, best of 3: 12.2 s per loop

#### @Romero Valentine answer

```py
rand = filter(lambda x: x>50, np.random.randint(1,100,100))
rand_list = list(rand)
```

> 35.9 µs ± 1.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

10,000,000 elements:

> 1 loop, best of 3: 3.41 s per loop

## Conclusions

- On simple tasks, these methods are all fine.
- On large arrays, numpy crushes the competition.

## Answers that provide more information

- @norok2
- @Alexander Cécile

Comment: I want to achieve it in list comprehension.

Comment: So, many awsers have been given for what you want. However, I still maintain the point, if you use numpy, try to use its built in method.

Comment: Incidentally this would be generally faster (but not necessarily more memory efficient) than any of the comprehension-based solutions. Also `my_list` name is kind of misleading, as that is actually an NumPy array.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis why do you want to use a list comprehension only? FlorianBernard is right, when working with numpy you should write idiomatic numpy code. That means no explicit loops, etc.

Comment: Also np.where as an alternative, check my answer

Comment: I made a little edit with times for creating an array of 10,000,000 elements, let me know what you think :) I might add some memory benchmarks too.

Comment: I like your edit, thank you. I'm suprise to see at the end no difference between mask and numpy.where solutions.

Comment: So was I, but it actually makes a lot of sense. In fact, the [docs for `where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) mention: "When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero()." Here `condition` would be `arr > 50`, which is a boolean mask. What this boils down to, is that in this situation the masking method and `where` method are practically identical: `arr = arr[arr > 50]` versus `arr = arr[(arr > 50).nonzero()]` I will make an edit to include this in the answer, since we're comparing all the methods.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58422690/5218354) for a more detailed comparison of *filtering* methods for NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you have a some code:

```
numbers = [np.random.randint(50, 100) for x in range(100)]
```

which should probably be

```
numbers = np.random.randint(50, 100, 100)
```

Then you are asking if there is a way of replicate this using `list`-comprehension combined with filtering, starting from something that reads like:

```
numbers = [np.random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(100) if ...]
```

The answer to this is in general **NO**.

The reason for this is that the condition-filtering syntax will act as a filter to the generated numbers, *after* the numbers are generated and tentatively yielded.

Therefore, while the code `[np.random.randint(50,100) for x in range(100)]` will generate 100 items, any method based on comprehension filtering or even explicit use of `filter()` will have an unknown number of elements (typically less than 100, depending on how many items do meet the specified condition).

To get to that level of control, you may use a `while`-based generator (which [cannot be included in a comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505891/using-while-in-list-comprehension-or-generator-expressions)), e.g.:

```
import numpy as np


def my_brand_new_generator(n, a=1, b=100):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        x = np.random.randint(a, b)
        if x > 50:
            yield x
            i += 1


numbers = list(my_brand_new_generator(100))
print(numbers[10])
# [94 97 50 53 53 89 59 69 71 86]

print(len(numbers))
# 100
```

By contrast:

```
numbers = [x for x in (np.random.randint(1,100) for iter in range(100)) if x > 50]
print(len(numbers))
# 54

x = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100)
numbers = x[x > 50]
print(len(numbers))
# 43
```

---

As side notes:

- the `my_brand_new_generator()` is to be considered only a *toy* example to illustrate the aforementioned idea.
- in general NumPy offers better alternatives to explicit iteration, so, when available, please use [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413656/5218354).
- for generating a single random integer, you can use [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) from the Python standard library.

Comment: What does "any method based on comprehension filtering or even explicit use of filter() will not have control over the number generated values" mean?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It means that you cannot tell beforehand how many items there will be in the following list: `[x for x in (random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)) if x > 50]`.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense! It might be a good idea to edit your answer to make that a bit clearer, since we do have control over the number of _generated_ values, just not over the result amount/amount after filtering.

Comment: Yes, much better :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, first generate your 100 numbers (or how many you need) between 1 & 100 here but again that's upto you, then iterate through them checking each one & only keeping the ones over 50...

```
y = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=100)
number = [x for x in y if x > 50]
```

Alternatively in one line...

```
number = [x for x in np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=100) if x > 50]
```

Comment: Yea I figured I could generate them first. I wanted to check I could use a sneaky one-liner. Thanks.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis have just added the one liner

Comment: Note that this would create an unnecessary temporary container, so it is not as memory efficient as it could.

Comment: sure but tha's not what was asked

Comment: I think @norok2 makes a good point. Even if it isn't directly related to the question it's probably best to write code that is solid overall. It's a good habit. You wouldn't include malware in your code because OP didn't ask "Create a list of random numbers and filter the list to only have numbers larger than 50, without getting any malware", right? ;)

Answer (score 1):

@FlorianBernard is right, do NOT mix Python lists and NumPy arrays. Stay in NumPy world, things would be faster anyway. THere is no equivalent in NumPy for python lists comprehension, because it operates on arrays, not on a single items one by one.

Anyway, there is a bit more complicated but more powerful alternative to @FlorianBernard answer, using [numpy.where function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

F.e., it allows fusion of filtered and baseline arrays into new one.
Simple code to start with

```
import numpy as np
q = np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000)
m = np.where(q > 50)
print(q[m])
```

Comment: I would also add a note on speed and memory efficiency comparison between `np.where()` and boolean masking.

Comment: Fear not, in this situation `where` is basically equivalent to masking! See my edit/comment to the answer by @FlorianBernard

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58422690/5218354) you can find some `np.where()` vs boolean mask slicing comparisons.

Comment: @norok2 well, timing is done already in Florian answer, so I didn't bother

Answer (score 1):

Be careful not to mix numpy and plain python when you have no reason to! You write that you could use `numbers = [np.random.randint(50,100) for x in range(100)]`, but it would be better to just do `np.random.randint(low=50, high=100, size=100)` to create an array of 100 random numbers.

Here is a pure python solution:

```py
import random

rand_nums = (random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(10))
arr = [val for val in rand_nums if val > 50]
```

Which can obviously be written as one line:

```
arr = [val for val in (random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(10)) if val > 50]
```

And here is a numpy solution:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=10)
arr = arr[arr > 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
numbers = [x for x in (np.random.randint(1,100) for iter in range(100)) if x > 50]
```

Step 1: `(np.random.randint(1,100) for iter in range(100))`: this generates 100 times, a random int between 1 and 100.

Step 2: `if x > 50`: The generated number is compared. If it's >50 it passes and is appended in the list.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work - since if the number is less than 50, the iteration is skipped.

Comment: Still only getting 56 numbers, versus 100. `>>> n = [x for x in (np.random.randint(1,100) for iter in range(100)) if x > 50]
>>> len(n)
56
`

Comment: You cannot get 100 always. If the number is less than 50 it is not appended. I think you are missing something

Comment: Note that in Python 3.8 you can simplify this quite a bit: `numbers = [x := random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100) if x > 50]`

Comment: Also it is worth noticing the use of the generator will not create a temporary useless container for the generated random items.

Comment: @makis, does iter acts as a some kind of placeholder for numbers generated by randint?

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `filter` function:

```py
rand = filter(lambda x: x>50, np.random.randint(1,100,100))
rand_list = list(rand)
```

No list comprehension necessary.

Comment: The OP asked for list comprehension-only solution

Answer (score -3):

Cheat it by creating a recursive function that will only unwind if the number is greater than 50.

```
import numpy as np

def genrandx():
    # Using a function allows you do to all sorts of crazy stuff and checks.
    x = np.random.randint(1,100)
    x = int((x*.5)**2)
    if (
        (x > 50) and
        (x < 1000) and 
        ( (x%3 == 0) or (x%3 == 0) )
       ): 
        return x 
    else: 
        return genrandx() 

numbers = [ genrandx() for x in range(100)]
print("({}){}".format(len(numbers), numbers))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(100)[930, 729, 306, 576, 600, 225, 324, 324, 462, 324, 462, 756, 324, 225, 702, 552, 576, 72, 81, 900, 600, 225, 930, 900, 576, 240, 552, 702, 441, 72, 462, 132, 144, 324, 72, 702, 462, 930, 72, 306, 240, 225, 870, 210, 729, 600, 420, 132, 240, 420, 441, 420, 72, 756, 225, 900, 72, 90, 72, 600, 72, 420, 210, 702, 240, 462, 600, 156, 81, 900, 144, 72, 225, 324, 144, 420, 600, 576, 729, 156, 900, 81, 756, 729, 702, 90, 462, 306, 600, 930, 729, 240, 552, 144, 90, 900, 420, 225, 600, 156]
```

Comment: The OP asked for list comprehension-only solution

Comment: @makis - This is a list comprehension

Comment: that uses an external function. I have already provided an answer using only list comprehension.

Comment: @Sayse it contains a list comprehension, but it is not one as you also defined a function

Comment: See [Can a lambda function call itself recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python) and use a recursive lambda to set the list item. Then you can call it a singular list comprehension-