# emulating built-in cycle function

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I've created the following emulator function for itertools.cycle in python.

```
def cycle1(s) :
   while True :
       for i in s :  
           yield i
```

However, I am not sure why the following produces a syntax error:

```
def cycle2(s) :
   return (i for i in s while True)
```

Why cannot I use while in list comprehension? How can I have an infinite loop within list comprehension?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using while in list comprehension or generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505891/using-while-in-list-comprehension-or-generator-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why cannot I use `while` in [the syntax for comprehensions and generator expressions]?

It just isn't defined to work that way. Maybe a future version might support it, if there is a clear proposal (PEP) and enough demand.

> How can I have an infinite loop within list comprehension?

with a `for` clause that loops over some unbounded generator. `itertools` provides a couple of those: `count` (produces increasing numbers endlessly) and `repeat` (keeps yielding the same value, unless an explicit count is provided). Alternately, you can build it yourself from the built-in `iter`:

```
>>> help(iter)
Help on built-in function iter in module builtins:

iter(...)
    iter(iterable) -> iterator
    iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator

    Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
    supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
    In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.
```

The first version clearly doesn't help, but for the second, all we need is a callable that returns some value, and a sentinel value that is a different value. E.g. `iter(lambda: True, False)`.

Answer (score 0):

It raises error because that syntax is not defined in Python! You can try:

```py
class MyGenerator:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
        self._ix = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._ix is None:
            self._ix = 0

        self._ix = (self._ix + 1) % self.s
        return self._ix

g = MyGenerator(5)

for i in range(20):
    print(next(g))
```

Comment: `MyGenerator` is like a cyclic version of `range`, right? How does that help OP?